EventSource closes after one minute with net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
my EventSource is constantly getting closed, always after one minute, with:
GET http://localhost:5002/api/resource/53f04e14fe/sse/event-stream net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)

I send a message from a server to the browser every 5 seconds.
Headers that I send as a response to the initial GET request sent from the browser:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
cache-control: no-cache
content-type: text/event-stream
date: Thu, 25 Apr 2024 12:52:25 GMT
server: Cowboy
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-accel-buffering: no

I checked browser logs (Chromium 124). I don't include content-length in my header.
[318448:318470:0425/134041.691951:VERBOSE1:url_request_http_job.cc(1564)] ShouldFixMismatchedContentLength() "http://localhost:5002/api/resource/b862ec5518/sse/event-stream" content-length = -1 pre total = 324 post total = 324

